# Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'transformClassesWithDexForDebug' during up-to-date check

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.2

i am new to android app development and trying to build a simple interface, i am getting this bug. how do i resolve it?

the whole bug statement is this :

Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'transformClassesWithDexForDebug' during up-to-date check.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\AndroidStudioProjects\thirdone\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\com.android.support-appcompat-v7-25.0.1_b5d942cb3c7f3d8ae436ecd262f1d7a26bba1e06\classes.dex (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Delete build folder and try cleaning and syncing the project again.To find build folder follow this path F:\AndroidStudioProjects\thirdone\app\.

Comment: It would be helpful to figure it out if you could post the full stack trace and and build.gradle code

Answer (score 4):

The issue in the latest android studio update is with the Instant Run feature.
There happens to be a serious issue with gradle, so you may either turn off the Anti-Virus or the Instant Run feature till then.

Resource: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229918

Answer (score 3):

I am using android studio 2.3 and solved this issue by disabling the anti-virus protection.