# Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'transformClassesWithDexForDebug' property 'streamOutputFolder' during up-to-date check

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on an android project. And I am facing a problem that while running app in android I am getting error i.e.

```
"Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'transformClassesWithDexForDebug' property 'streamOutputFolder' during up-to-date check.
```

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\5\slice_0\classes.dex'."

And if I disable my antivirus I am able to run my app successfully and no error will occur. I am not able to understand what is happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136640/errorfailed-to-capture-snapshot-of-output-files-for-task-transformclasseswithd

Answer (score 1):

its a privilege issue, give your folder rights to everyone and full-control